# How to get location from text using OpenNLP?

Tags: java, location, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am using  chunking for tagging the data and get the location from the text initially i try to extract noun phrase from next when we use noun phrase name also mentioned as noun phrase so it can't use.then i moved to location ner of core nlp
i try to run the below code

```
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
```

InputStream inputStreamTokenizer = new 
         FileInputStream("D:\project\Relation Extraction in Text Document\Libraray\parsing/en-token.bin"); 
      TokenizerModel tokenModel = new TokenizerModel(inputStreamTokenizer);

```
  //String paragraph = "Mike and Smith are classmates"; 
  String paragraph = "Tutorialspoint is located in Hyderabad"; 

  //Instantiating the TokenizerME class 
  TokenizerME tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenModel); 
  String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(paragraph); 

  //Loading the NER-location moodel 
  InputStream inputStreamNameFinder = new 
     FileInputStream("D:\\project\\Relation Extraction in Text Document\\Libraray\\parsing/en-ner-location.bin");       
  TokenNameFinderModel location = new TokenNameFinderModel(inputStreamNameFinder); 

  //Instantiating the NameFinderME class 
  NameFinderME nameFinder;      
        nameFinder = new NameFinderME(location);

  //Finding the names of a location 
  Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(tokens);        
  //Printing the spans of the locations in the sentence 
 for(Span s: nameSpans)        
     System.out.println(s.toString()+"  "+tokens[s.getStart()]);
```

I Got an error that "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet."

An error symbol at"  nameFinder = new NameFinderME(location);" saying that "exmp.TokenNameFinderModel cannot be converted to opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel" what is reson for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect imports, here is a working version:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
```

and the output: `[4..5) location  Hyderabad`

Comment: Thank you bro...it's  work fine,,but it only works for that i try another example....but can't spot it... EG:Jhone works at kollam